# Declaring anonymous type as array correctly to keep scope

Tags: c#, linq, c#-4.0

All I want to do is declare `var place` correctly so it is still in scope once I get to the `foreach` loop. I'm assuming I need to declare it before the `if` statement for `connections`. Is this a correct assumption and if so how do I declare it? Thanks!

```
using (var db = new DataClasses1DataContext())
        {
            if (connections == "Connections")
            {
                var place = (from v in db.pdx_aparts
                             where v.Latitude != null && v.Region == region && v.WD_Connect >= 1
                             select new
                             {
                                 locName = v.Apartment_complex.Trim().Replace(@"""", ""),
                                 latitude = v.Latitude,
                                 longitude = v.Longitude
                             }).Distinct().ToArray();
            }
            else
            {
                var place = (from v in db.pdx_aparts
                             where v.Latitude != null && v.Region == region &&    ((v.WD_Connect == null) || (v.WD_Connect == 0))
                             select new
                             {
                                 locName = v.Apartment_complex.Trim().Replace(@"""", ""),
                                 latitude = v.Latitude,
                                 longitude = v.Longitude
                             }).Distinct().ToArray();

            }

            foreach (var result in place)
            ....
```

Comment: You could fold the `if` into the `where` instead, and only have a single query? I don't think you can declare an anonymously typed variable before you assign to it.

Comment: @Blorgbeard might prevent SQL Server from using indexes. Depends on the OPs schema.

Comment: @usr I am using indexes. Thanks for noting that

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can create an array with a single entry whose value you ignore later:

```
// Note: names *and types* must match the ones you use later on.
var place = new[] { new { locName = "", latitude = 0.0, longitude = 0.0 } };
if (connections = "Connections")
{
    // Note: not a variable declaration
    place = ...;
}
else
{
    place = ...;
}
```

This works because every use of anonymous types using properties with the same names and types, in the same order, will use the same concrete type.

I think it would be better to make the code *only* differ in the parts that it needs to though:

```
var query = v.db.pdx_aparts.Where(v => v.Latitude != null && v.Region == region);
query = connections == "Connections"
    ? query.Where(v => v.WD_Connect >= 1)
    : query.Where(v => v.WD_Connect == null || v.WD_Connect == 0);
var places = query.Select(v =>  new
                          {
                              locName = v.Apartment_complex
                                         .Trim()
                                         .Replace("\"", ""),
                              latitude = v.Latitude,
                              longitude = v.Longitude
                          })
                  .Distinct()
                  .ToArray();
```

Here it's much easier to tell that the *only* part which depends on the `connections` value is the section of the query which deals with `WD_Connect`.

Answer (score 2):

You could convert the `if` to a `?:`.

```
var place = connections == "Connections" ? monsterQuery1 : monsterQuery2;
```

I do not think this is a good solution because your queries are too big (unreadable).

It would be much better if you introduced a **named class** that you use instead of the anonymous type. R# does that for you in a "light bulb menu" refactoring.

Comment: Changing to use a named class wouldn't *in itself* reduce the big queries though. There are better ways of tackling that part which don't require a named class.

Comment: @JonSkeet I agree, your answer is better. More holistic.

Answer (score 1):

you could just use the 1 query since they are pretty much the same, and just add the extra condition in the where clause

```
var place = (from v in db.pdx_aparts
             where v.Latitude != null && v.Region == region 
             &&  connections == "Connections" 
             ? v.WD_Connect >= 1 
             : ((v.WD_Connect == null) || (v.WD_Connect == 0))
             select new
             {
                 locName = v.Apartment_complex.Trim().Replace(@"""", ""),
                 latitude = v.Latitude,
                 longitude = v.Longitude
             }).Distinct().ToArray();


 foreach (var result in place)
 ....
```

Comment: This might prevent SQL Server from using indexes. Depends on the OPs schema. It will execute but the performance profile might be worse.