# LINQ Where instead of Select

Tags: c#, linq

I need to do this:

```
if(...)
{
    var query2 = query.Select(i => new { Balance = i.Balance * i.RateValue, Date = i.Date });
}
```

Of course I may do it, but then I'll have a problem:

```
var list = query2.ToList();
```

How I can implement this? Maybe something like this:

```
if(accountName == "Safe" && currency == "Br")
    {
        query = query.Where(i => new { Balance = i.Balance * i.RateValue, Date = i.Date });
    }
```

But this doesn't work.

Comment: How is `query2.ToList()` "a problem"? And I have no idea what you are trying to show us in the last bit of code. `Where` and `Select` have completely different purposes.

Comment: @JLRishe: i guess he can't access the variable `query2` from outside the `if`. So he tries to assign an `IEnumerable<anonymous type>` to a variable which he cannot declare before the if. Then this is the duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14348658/declaring-anonymous-type-as-array-correctly-to-keep-scope

Answer (score 0):

Your question is lacking context. What is the type of `i` and which properties does it have more? Do you want to filter on account name and currency? Also `Where` and `Select` are completely different functions.

Or did you mean something like this?

```
var query = query.Where(i => i.AccountName == "Safe" && i.Currency == "Br")
                 .Select(i => new { Balance = i.Balance * i.RateValue, Date = i.Date });
```

Comment: I just wanna to convert one anonymous type to another. In if statement.